# ASP.Net Webservice - Constructors with Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I'm fairly new to WebService developement and have just set up my own webservice (ASP.Net 3.5, Visual Studio 2008 .asmx file).
I can not find a way of setting up my webservice to take parameters on the constructor.
If i create a constructor that takes parameters, it is not then shown when i hook up to the webservice from my application (it only shows a parameterless constructor). 
Am i missing something blatently obvious, or is this not possible (and why not)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "constructor for my webservice", do you mean "constructor for **the proxy that communicates with** my webservice"?

You may need to write a wrapper for the proxy if you need to handle authentication tokens and the like (this is the approach that the [Flickr.Net](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/) open source project took)

Comment: By "need to", I mean "want to", of course -- depends how much you like the consumers of your service...

Comment: Ah, i was missing the fact that it's the proxy that needs the constructor. I will make the Webservice authenticate every request, and create a wrapper for the proxy for use on the client that has a constructor taking authentication details. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

it is meaningless to have parameters of web service constructor. web service communicate with client only on requests. constructor is called by web server internals automatically